# Having trouble with creating a tree from a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to turn an int vector into a binary search tree. I am using Cygwin on Windows if that matters. For some reason, after tracing I found that "next" has the same address every iteration of the loop. Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

edit: replaced my empty check line with "if (numbers.empty()) return;"

```cpp
Tree::Tree(std::vector<int> numbers){
        if (numbers.empty()) return;
        node *current = &root;
        current->num = *numbers.begin();
        node *next;
        for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin() + 1; it != numbers.end(); it++){
                next = new node();
                next->num = *it;
                if (*it >= current->num){
                        current->right = next;
                        current = current->right;
                } else {
                        current->left = next;
                        current = current->left;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: `if (numbers.begin() == numbers.end())` It's too late to make this check *after* you've already dereferenced `*numbers.begin()`. If the condition is true, then your program has already exhibited undefined behavior.

Comment: `if (numbers.begin() == numbers.end())` should be replaced with `if (numbers.empty())`, and needs to be moved above the dereferencing of `begin()`.

Comment: That's not at all how a binary search tree works. You are effectively building a linked list: no node ever has both `left` and `right` pointers set.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I know it won't be balanced. It's for a class and it's supposed to be like that for some reason.

Comment: It's not just that it's not balanced - it's not a BST at all. The point of BST is that all smaller values are in the left subtree, and all larger values are in the right subtree. But you put **all** values either to the left or to the right of the root (depending on whether the second value is smaller or larger). You never even have two sub-trees, in any node.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oh, you are right...

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. Using a debugger you can run your program one line at a time, allowing you to insect the values of all variables, monitor how they change, as each line of your program executes, and observe your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. What you are really asking is how to use a debugger.